# React native router flux params not working (are UNDEFINED)

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm moving to another Scene and sending parameters, but when I print the param (I use log.console({param: value}), I get an 'undefined'. Here is the code

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.addToOrderButton}
                              onPress={() => Actions.addToOrder({description: 'description', price: 'price'})}>
              <View style={{ flex: 1,justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Text style={{color: '#FFF', fontSize: 12}}>Add to order</Text>
            </View></TouchableOpacity>
```

The Router.js is

```
<Drawer key="orders" contentComponent={DrawerMenu}>
         <Scene key="drawerMain" component={OrderMenu} title="Menu" initial />
         <Scene key="addToOrder" component={AddToOrder} title="Add to Order" />
        </Drawer>
```

Anybody what is the problem?
Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I'm using redux. That's why doen't work

Answer (score 0):

in second page you should call your param with something like this 
you should use props

in addToOrder screen

console.log(this.props.description)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with the Drawer.

Check here: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/3374